Can't compile a standalone app in 14.1
I read the article reviewing the innovations in version 14.1 and am absolutely thrilled to be able to build a standalone app. I tried to replicate the example from the article in an even shorter form, but I get errors during compilation
(*test.nb*)
<<CCompilerDriver`

CreateLibrary[
    File["C:\\Users\\Kirill\\Projects\\Internal\\Source\\test.c"], 
    "test", 
    "IncludeDirectories" -> {
        "C:\\Program Files\\Wolfram Research\\Wolfram\\14.1\\SystemFiles\\Components\\StandaloneApplicationsSDK\\Windows-x86-64", 
        "C:\\Program Files\\Wolfram Research\\Wolfram\\14.1\\SystemFiles\\IncludeFiles\\C"
    }
]

//test.c
#include <stdio.h>

#include "WolframLanguageRuntimeV1SDK.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    wlr_runtime_conf configuration; 
    char *result; 

    wlr_InitializeRuntimeConfiguration(&configuration);
    configuration.containmentSetting = WLR_UNCONTAINED; 

    WLR_SDK_START_RUNTIME(
        WLR_EXECUTABLE, 
        WLR_LICENSE_OR_SIGNED_CODE_MODE, 
        "C:\\Program Files\\Wolfram Research\\Wolfram\\14.1", 
        &configuration
    ); 

    wlr_StringData(wlr_Eval(wlr_E(wlr_Symbol("StringJoin"), "123", "456")), &result, NULL); 
    printf("%s\n", result);

    wlr_Release(&result); 
    return 0; 
}


I am using Wolfram 14.1. The compiler is Microsoft Visual Studio 2022. WIndows 11 operating system. As a result, I get this error:


As shown in the example in the blog post, you have to also include the .lib file, namely: CreateExecutable[{"test.c", "C:\\Program Files\\Wolfram Research\\Wolfram\\14.1\\SystemFiles\\Components\\StandaloneApplicationsSDK\\Windows-x86-64\\StandaloneApplicationsSDK.lib"}, ...]

Thanks! This works!

Are you also able to get a result? Because while I do get a compiled file, it seems to crash at the line wlr_StringData(...).

The code compiled and runs, but it doesn't work properly. This is better than nothing. As soon as I figure it out, I'll complete the question!

Perhaps this Live CEOing might be of use. If I write wlr_AddStdoutHandler(wlr_DefaultStdoutHandler, NULL); wlr_EvalString(wlr_String("Print[Integrate[x,x]];"));, I do get a result.

So you shouldn't use pure string, but you should wrap them in wlr_String. This works: wlr_StringData(wlr_Eval(wlr_E(wlr_Symbol("StringJoin"), wlr_String("123"), wlr_String("456"))), &result, NULL).

Interesting! I was able to reproduce Domen's example, the compilation (for the WL expression “Print[Integrate[x,x]];”) went through without errors. The finished compiled “test.exe” correctly reproduces the result at Windows command line level (formatted as if I had evaluated directly from the kernel).
Now the crucial question: how do I distribute the compilation, or what exactly do I have to distribute? It can't be the exe file itself, can it (only 155 KB in size)? What “package” do I have to put together in order to be able to deliver it to third parties in an executable form? Thanks!

@ArminVollmer yes, this works for mee too. But doesnot work on system without wolfram kernel.

Yes, I had to make the same observation. I'm very curious to see how this will develop with the upcoming beta program and what restrictions will be placed on being able to sign your own code.
